# Convert a list in several data frames

Tags: r

I have a list with different elements inside:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c("a","b","c"))
df3 <- data.frame(col = c("a","c","f","h","j"), col1 = c("a1","c2","f3","h4","j5"))
aList <- list(df1,df2,df3)
```

I would like to have one data frame for each element of the list. Basically I would like that `aList` to be back to `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`.

Comment: `list2env(setNames(aList, c("df1", "df2", "df3")), envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: You could use `attach` or `assign`, but both are ill-advised. Usually a list of data frames is actually the best way to go. [Here's a nice post on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050)

Comment: It took me 3 hours to get to that!!!! Thanks d.b. One more question: that works for a list with 3 elements. df1, df2, df3. How can I do it for several data frames without the need to to c("df1", "df2", "df3")?

Comment: @BrunoGuarita, replace `c("df1", "df2", "df3")` with `paste0("df", sequence(length(aList)))`

Comment: @d.b if this is not a duplicate, then perhaps convert your comment to an answer?